# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly | Xamarin Release Build

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on an app in Visual Studio using Xamarin. I want to build in release mode in order to compile an APK so that I can have a friend install the app to test what I have done so far.

Upon building in release mode I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Mono.Linker.TypeReferenceExtensions.<GetMethods>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.TryMatchMethod(TypeReference type, MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.<GetBaseMethodsInInterfaceHierarchy>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.MapVirtualInterfaceMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.MapVirtualMethods(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.MapType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.MapType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.TypeMapStep.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() PartyMe.Android
```

There are a lot of results for a google search of the issue. All of them recommend targeting the latest Android SDK or API 21. I am already targeting API 26 (Oreo). A few also say to update Xamarin.Forms to the latest version, but I am not even using Xamarin.Forms.

I have also tried closing / reopening and cleaning / rebuilding.

Comment: The linker is most likely failing on a specific assembly. Being able to isolate said assembly will help you work towards linkskipping it as this is most likely a bug in the linker that requires investigation.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to track down which assembly is causing the issue? Just thinking about Xamarin seems to require references.

Comment: In a new sample project, add your nuget references one by one and build each time until the linker error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.X version that causing Linker issue for Xamarin.Android project compile in Release mode. I tested on 15.5.5, the problem still exist.
Unfortunately, so far the only workaround is to revert back to VS2017 15.4.5

Same problem reported in Xamarin forum:
 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/112783/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly?
How to revert back to older version of VS2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not compiling the PCL/Shared project in your solution.
If it's a project that was ongoing/working with some references to Nuget packages I would clean the solution, delete the `/bin` & `/obj` folders and delete the `packages` folder.
Otherwise, I would delete and re-insert manually all the packages references in your PCL/Shared project.